# Is there visual flash effect for editing?

Tags: vim, vi

What we are looking for is to visually flash briefly the affected areas of vim editing in normal mode. For example, when editing

```
if (true) {
    //line to be deleted
}
```

if we do `dd` on `//line to be deleted`, this affected area should be flashed before deleting, the same we can do using `Vd`. What we are looking is the same effect as that of `Vd` using `dd`. This should work for all editing operations like `c`, `y` etc.

We tried mapping it with `nnoremap dd Vd` to test for a single line, no luck. Not even sure, if we should map like this.

Google search did not turn up anything satisfactory. Is there any known plugin out there? Any code which can be plug into vim will be also be great

Comment: What's wrong with `Vd` ?

Comment: Nothing other than a extra keywstrock. It will become pretty heavy to type everytime `v/V` for every editing command.

Comment: I mean you can `nnoremap y V`, `nnoremap d V`, and so on.. However, this would break other things. If you don't use that other things it should work for you

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at the code of [haya14busa/vim-operator-flashy](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-operator-flashy).

Comment: Thanks, This seems to be good starting point

Answer (score 5):

There are many things to tweak in the examples I give, but they may be a good start to solve your problem.

You can use `:redraw` and `:sleep` to draw the selection for a moment during the execution of a function.

Here is an example with `dd`:

```
nmap <silent> dd :call Com_dd()<cr>

function! Com_dd() range
    " Enter visual mode:
    normal! V

    " Select multiple lines, when there's a range:
    let morelines = a:lastline - a:firstline
    if morelines != 0
        exe "normal! ".morelines."j"
    endif

    " Redraw the screen so we can see the selection:
    redraw

    " Sleeps 200ms:
    sleep 200 m

    " Delete the selected lines:
    normal! d
endf
```

It can be called with a range, for example : `3dd`.

For commands with motions, it's a bit more tricky, but you can get close
to the desired behaviour, here is an example for the `c` command:

```
nmap <silent> c :set opfunc=Com_c<cr>g@

function! Com_c(type)
    let curpos = getpos('.')

    if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use gv command.
        silent exe "normal! gv"
    elseif a:type == 'line'
        silent exe "normal! '[V']"
    else
        silent exe "normal! `[v`]"
    endif

    redraw

    sleep 200 m

    normal! d
    startinsert
    call setpos('.', curpos)
endf
```

This last example doesn't handle ranges, so `3cw` will not work (but `c3w` will work).

See `:h g@` for help about mapping an operator.

**But** it leads to some new problems : the `.` doesn't work anymore with these commands, for example.
Another example is : the standard `cw` command doesn't delete any space after the word, but my example does.

You may find some solutions about these new problems, but I don't have any, now.

Comment: Thanks @yolenoyer. Will evaluate and get back to you