# Copy & Paste Vim effects

Tags: vim, ideavim

Is it possible to add, an "fade-in" textual animation while copying in Vim?

For example,

If I typed:

> 3yy

I would like Vim to momentarily blink the three lines that I copied. How can I do this?

Comment: This looks like the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171726/is-there-visual-flash-effect-for-editing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there visual flash effect for editing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171726/is-there-visual-flash-effect-for-editing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to file a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM